# PHP in jQuery tab

Tags: php, jquery, tabs

I want to create button to add tabs with body tabs
Please take look at the code where it says

```
$('#tabs1').tabs('add', 'lorem.txt', xxxxx' .....
```

as you can see `'lorem.txt'` is from where the information is retrieved to show in the body tabs,
I want to put `php` code and forms inside `tabs body` and not use `'lorem.txt'`
The problem is that it will not work if I put php code inside jquery.

My question is, is there any other way it can done to show forms using `php` code when person click button to add `tabs`?
I'm using `div` tag. Here is my code.

```
<script>
(function() {
    $(function() {
        var tab_counter = 0;
        $('#tabs1').tabs({
            closable: true,
            cache:true,
            add: function(e, ui){
                $('#tabs1').tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
            }
        });
        $('#tab_creator').click(function(){
            tab_counter += 1;
            $('#tabs1').tabs('add', 'lorem.txt', 'Tab ' + tab_counter);
            return false;
        });
        $('#tabs2').tabs();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h2 class="ui-widget ui-widget-header">closable Tabs</h2>
<input id="tab_creator" type="button" value="Add New Tab">
<div id="tabs1">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs1-1">tabs one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs1-2">tabs two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs1-3">tabs three</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs1-1">
        <p> tabs one body</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs1-2">
        <p>tabs two body</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs1-3">
        <p>tabs three body</p>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: did u add jquery ui file?

Comment: Does the PHP file work when you load it directly in the location bar? Is it valid XHTML?

Comment: i do not want to use ui file, i want to put php code instead of file. there is way!

Comment: Of course. Replace `tabs one body` with PHP and remove the load or the complete tab creator

Comment: i know about that part, but what i'm talking about when person click button to add new tabs and want to show forms using php inside of body tabs. how that works!

Comment: did you tried `$('#tabs1').tabs('add', 'myprettytab.php', 'Tab ' + tab_counter);` ?

Comment: yes i have tried that it didn't work well...any other way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JS code is placed directly at `<head>` (as your example):

```
$('#tabs1').tabs('add', '<?php echo $filename; ?>', 'Tab ' + tab_counter);
```

Otherwise, you need something like this:

```
$('#tabs1').tabs('add', $( '#tabs1' ).attr( 'data-filename' ), 'Tab ' + tab_counter);
```

... where you put the PHP code inside the data-filename attribute in #tabs1:

```
<div id="tabs1" data-filename="<?php echo $filename; ?>">
```

About data attribute: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+data)